# CocoaPods Installation Error msg FilePermissionError

Tags: xcode, cocoapods, macos-big-sur

Not able to install CocoaPods

Xcode - 13.2.1
macOs BigSur - 11.6.2

Error
ERROR: While executing gem ... (Gem::FilePermissionError)
You don't have write permissions for the /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.6/usr/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0 directory.

Comment: Did you manage to resolve this issue? I have the same problem.

Answer (score 0):

1. curl -L https://get.rvm.io%C2%A0%7C bash -s stable
2. rvm install ruby-3.1.1
3. sudo gem install cocoapods

Comment: Please explain shortly about commands you have pasted.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: you need to install rvm  with stable  Open Terminal                                           
 curl -L https://get.rvm.io | bash -s stable                                                     
Reopen Terminal                                                                                                    
rvm install ruby-3.1.1 rvm use ruby-3.1.1 rvm --default use 3.1.1                     Then this installed cocoapods as expected                                                      
sudo gem install cocoapods

Answer (score 0):

Try installing cocoa pods with **Brew**.

To install Brew, run following commands on your Terminal.

```
export HOMEBREW_NO_INSTALL_FROM_API=1                          
/bin/bash -c "$(curl -fsSL https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Homebrew/install/master/install.sh)"

echo 'eval "$(/opt/homebrew/bin/brew shellenv)"' >> ~/.zprofile

eval "$(/opt/homebrew/bin/brew shellenv)"
```

Once Brew is successfully installed, you can run following command to install cocoapods.

```
brew install cocoapods
```

*If you face permission error in any directory then you can run this command.*

```
cd <your path mentioned in the error>

sudo chmod 400
```